# Wordpress - How add class to navbar ( bs4navwalker ) when in front-page, in functions.php

Tags: php, css, wordpress, class, addition

I'm beginner in web developing and I'm trying to understand how could add fixed-top class CSS in my navbar menu using bs4navwalker,
only when i'm in front-page

When I'm in home page i should have:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

In the other pages:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
//Before wallker add this
    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
      $navBarClasses = 'navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary';
    } else {
      $navBarClasses = 'navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary';
    }
//Insert variable $navBarClasses in walker param 'menu_class' =>
    wp_nav_menu([
         'menu'            => 'top',
         'theme_location'  => 'top',
         'container'       => 'div',
         'container_id'    => 'bs4navbar',
         'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
         'menu_id'         => false,
         'menu_class'      => $navBarClasses,
         'depth'           => 2,
         'fallback_cb'     => 'bs4navwalker::fallback',
         'walker'          => new bs4navwalker()
       ]);
    ?>
```